# Let $X$ and $Y$ random variables, $\{X_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$, and $\{Y_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ samples. Is $\{(X_{1},Y_{1})\}_{i=1}^{n}$ a sample of $Z=(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, sampling

Let $X$ and $Y$ two random variables with density distribution function $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ respectively. We assume that $(X,Y)$ is a random variable on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ where 
$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A)=\iint_{A}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)dxdy. \tag{*}$$

Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$, and  $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n} $ samples of $X$ and $Y$ respectivelly.

**The question:** Is $(X_{1},Y_{1}),\ldots,(X_{n},Y_{n})$ a sample of random variable $Z=(X,Y)$?

If the answer is negative, how from $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$, and  $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n} $  I generate a sample of the random variable $Z=(X,Y)$?

Comment: Writing the density of $(X,Y)$ as the product $f_Xf_Y$, you implicitly assume $X,Y$ are independent. In this case, the answer to your question is "yes"; but if they are **not** independent, then "no," not in general. Were you aware of that implicit assumption you're making, when you wrote your question?

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in the case in which $X$ and $Y$ are distributed equally, that is, $f_{X}=f_{Y}$. in this case, **what would happen?** Furthermore, in this case, is $(X_{1},X_{1}),\ldots, (X_{n},X_{n})$ a sample of  $Z=(X,Y)$?

Comment: No. You still may not have independence. What if $X=Y$ a.s.? Then $Z$ should always be of the form $(x,x)$, which you won't get with your scheme.

Comment: (Say $X$ and $Y$ are both uniform on $[0,1]$, but such that $X=Y$ a.s. Then a.s. a realization of $Z$ is of the form $(x,x)$ with $x\in[0,1]$; but taking samples $x,y$ from $X$ and $Y$ independently and outputting $(x,y)$, you will get $x=y$ with probability 0.)

Comment: And again, your sentence starting with "We know that $(X,Y)$" is **false**. The density you write does not hold in general if $X,Y$ are not independent: you cannot claim $f_{(X,Y)}=f_Xf_Y$ in general.

Comment: (OTOH, if you assume independence of $X,Y$ then what you ask is immediately true)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, finally, do you know any book where I can study this in detail?

Comment: Not really... There are many of them, but I can't think of any one in particular. Lecture notes about probability and measure theory, I guess?